# Phone calls cause apps to delete

Tags: iphone

Every time my son gets a call on his iPhone all his apps & everything get deleted. Why does ths keep happening? This is his 3rd new phone and it keeps happening. He restores it then someone will call him & everything gets deleted again & again.

Comment: any caller or specific number? what non standard apps does he have?

Comment: It isn't jailbroken, is it?